# Lord Ram has abandoned me, I do not feel his love anymore. What do I do?

Tags: rama

It’s weird, it’s as if my lord is angry or just impervious to my pain.

Comment: This isn't some Christian deity, if you are devoted and believe in Īśvara or its forms, no one is actually abandoned. No matter what you do, no matter what doctrine you practice, no matter if you are believer or not. No one is abandoned, no one is thrown to hell just because you don't believe or worship Rāma or some other deity. Or you can take another view that everyone is abandoned, which a devotee may not agree with. And if you do believe in God, no matter what you do, you are just an ant always, and that's how everyone else is too for a Hindu God, if he exists.

Comment: Your pain may be fruit of your own karma. Sri Ram can't break law of karma for a devotee but he will give you strength to bear the pain. I mean purely in a religious sense. No offense

Comment: How do you know He has abandoned you ? Also, are you very sure He is your Ishth-Dev ? From what I understand, if you have chosen Ishth-Dev that is right for you, this sorta feeling shouldn’t happen very much ? (I kind of made this mistake. Long story. One of many many mistakes I made ) Anyways. Is possible if you  are feeling this way could be an indication of some greater issue like choosing inaccurately or that bhakti marg could be in addition to karm or gyan type path for you ? I chose the wrong path when I started too by the way  Made every mistake is possible to make. No worries 

Comment: Yep, indeed, bhakti isn't suitable for everyone, only those who can self-surrender can walk on that path. Not everyone can, and it's alright. It's not the only path but just one of many. In some systems, bhakti isn't anyway even considered a path which gives mokṣa (such as Śaṅkara's advaita, in later advaita however bhakti is fused by Madhusūdana Sarasvatī)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: if he really abandoned u, you wouldn't need his love at all..